# Questions where answers can not be accepted, should not count towards the accept rate

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, accept-rate

I just noticed this question: [Broken stop button on Vista SP2 Media Center, any ideas when this will be fixed?](https://superuser.com/questions/4331/broken-stop-button-on-vista-sp2-media-center-any-ideas-when-this-will-be-fixed)

which in the past had a bounty, counts towards my accept rate.

As it stands the only way for me to fix this, is to turn my question into community wiki.

Should questions which were bounties and no answer was accepted, count towards my accept rate?

Comment: I just love how people abbreviate "Community Wiki" with "cc-wiki"

Comment: Always thought it was shortened to, "poll!" or "cwiki".

Comment: Declined as [accept rate is no longer shown with on the usercard for a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164654/140951).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they should.

You didn't accept an answer, whether there was a bounty or not. Considering there was no accepted bounty and therefore no-one got the bounty indicates that you did not accept all your questions.

If the accept rate is important for you then make it a CW.

Comment: Nice, so not only did you question the accept rate policy, but also had to end up accepting an answer from someone who disagreed with you (I think) as noone else answered...