# Accept check marks are not visible on one of my unaccepted questions

Tags: support, stack-overflow

The accept check marks are not visible on one of my unaccepted questions on SO:
[Custom HTTP Basic Authentication for ASP.NET Web Services on .NET 3.5/VS 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490627/custom-http-basic-authentication-for-asp-net-web-services-on-net-3-5-vs-2008)

I am logged in and I see the check marks on other unaccepted questions. Is there a special rule for accepting questions that I am missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- (maybe obvious, but) are you logged in as the correct user? (I can only see one `eed3si9n`, so I don't think this is the problem, but sometimes people start with an unregistered account and then have a *different* registered account - which can be merged by moderators if needed)
- Did you have an (unsuccessful) bounty or anything like that?

Update: I checked the logs; yes, you did:

> eed3si9n -> Bounty creation of 100 rep on question id = 490627 Feb 4 at 5:33 () (-50 rep)

If you add a bounty, then the ability to select an answer is removed after the bounty ends. You didn't select a winner, and none had 2 votes so none was auto-selected. See also [Questions where answers can not be accepted, should not count towards the accept rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16836/questions-where-answers-can-not-be-accepted-should-not-count-towards-the-accept)

Comment: I guess that makes sense.